# Is there a single word for “login/logout”?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a single word that means both logging in and logging out?

I have a single file which I currently have named as `Login`. But it does more than logging in, it also logs out. I'm looking for a word that encompasses both login and logout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center says that choosing names for things — no matter whether those be for babies or businesses, programs or products — is outside the scope of our site. We cannot help you pick your favorite name for a software entity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Logging in is authenticating and logging out is deauthenticating (or, sometimes, unauthenticating). Code that does both handles **authentication**.

An example of *authentication* being used as a hypernym like this can be found in the [CakePHP docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout):

> ## Authentication (login and logout)
>
> We’re now ready to add our authentication layer. In CakePHP this is handled by the `AuthComponent`, a class responsible for requiring login for certain actions, handling user sign-in and sign-out, and also authorizing logged in users to the actions they are allowed to reach.

Similarly, the Laravel (another PHP framework) documentation page titled [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) also covers both logging in and logging out.

Comment: "logging out is unauthenticating" - I've never heard "unauthenticate" or "unauthenticating", do you have any references for them? Given the well-established definitions of "authenticate" and "unauthenticated", "unauthenticate" (which is not in the dictionary) as a verb doesn't really make sense. Logging out ends the current session, it doesn't change the fact that the user had been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name "user session" or simply "session" - this is more reflective of the behavior of your file which begins and ends an authenticated session for the user. Programmatically, by the way, this is exactly what happens: a user session begins with a login and is terminated with a logout. The word "authentication" suggested above is basically equivalent to "login", in and of itself it does not imply logout. CakePHP docs are misusing the term because  they are trying to envelope three distinct tasks in it: login, authorization, and logout.